# Large usb-devices wont show up in boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I am trying to create bootable USB-Sticks. 
My problem is that I am only able to boot from my small 2GB Stick.

No matter what I try, I have tested different linux distributions and Win10 iso (using dd, Unetbootin or startup disk creator for linux distros and WinUSB for Win10). 
I am only able to create a bootable stick using some small distrobution on my 2GB Stick.

All my other sticks and SD-Cards wont show up in boot-menu. 
I have already tried to only use a 5GB Partition on my 8-16GB Sticks. 
Doesn't work either. 
Same problem with trying my Linux-Puppy iso which works fine on my 2GB Stick but wont work with my 8GB and 16GB stick.

I have tried enable/disable UEFI-Boot and secure boot and returned to default settings. Nothing helped.

**My setup:**

Lenovo L460 with SSD with one partition with 120GB (around 50% used, its my current system Ubuntu 17.10) and 60GB with unpartitioned space (that should be my Win10 partition soon).
I am currently trying to install Win10 alongside to my Ubuntu installation (I know, that it is not the common way and I know that I will need my LiveUSB to reinstall grub after that and all my files are backed up).

I will provide further information if needed.

Comment: If anyone is totally confused and has tried everything to get his bootable stick to show up in BIOS, I may have found a solution: After struggling with different settings for over two days, I solved my problem by using an external powered USB-Hub.